# operation must use an updateable query - access

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2007

I want to update a table by using the join in access - 2007

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A INNER JOIN (SELECT ACCODE, SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_AMOUNT 
FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY ACCODE) B ON A.ACCODE = B.ACCODE
SET A.TRIAL = A.TRIAL + SUM_AMOUNT
```

it gives me error that

> operation must use an updateable query

i have try with below query and no error is here

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ACCODE = B.ACCODE
SET A.TRIAL = A.TRIAL + SUM_AMOUNT
```

please help me to find what is wrong with first query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the reason Access treats your query as non-updateable is due to the subquery `GROUP BY`.  You should be able to create an updateable query by using `DSum`.

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 AS a
SET a.TRIAL = a.TRIAL
    + DSum("AMOUNT", "TABLE2", "ACCODE=" & a.ACCODE)
```

If `ACCODE` is text instead of numeric data type, add quotes around the value in the `DSum` expression.

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 AS a
SET a.TRIAL = a.TRIAL
    + DSum("AMOUNT", "TABLE2", "ACCODE='" & a.ACCODE & "'")
```

Comment: thanks that solved my problem, sorry for selecting the sql-server tag that makes the confusion

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and it was due to permissions on the table. I made a copy of the linked table to test my update query on, and kept getting this error message. I was pretty sure my query would be ok (it was a simple update) so I ran it on the actual table and I didn't get the error. Just wanted to add this for anyone else that comes across this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

this error also comes when you are accessing database which is on different PC. so give write  permission from security tab of folder and also give write access on sharing permission option. 
In my case this is worked

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mandeep, that is the way ms-access works.

```sql
UPDATE Table1 As T1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.F1 = T2.F1
SET T1.F2 = T2.F2
```

This query raises 'operation must use an updateable query' erro when T2 is a query, ***even when you are not updating T2.***