# Update with Subquery in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make this query work but I'm getting errors:

```
    UPDATE SIRADATOK T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT sirid, MAX(SzolgaltatasokDatumig) AS MAXDATE
    FROM ADOK GROUP BY SIRID HAVING MAX(SzolgaltatasokDatumig)<>' ' AND
    MAX(SzolgaltatasokDatumig) IS NOT NULL)  AS T2 ON T1.SIRID=T2.sirid 
    SET MegvaltasIdeje = MAXDATE;
```

The error I get:

**"Operation must use updatable query"**

I tried this way too:

```
    UPDATE T2 
    SET T1.MegvaltasIdeje = T2.MAXDATE
    FROM SIRADATOK T1, (SELECT sirid, MAX(SzolgaltatasokDatumig) AS MAXDATE 
    FROM ADOK GROUP BY SIRID HAVING MAX(SzolgaltatasokDatumig)<>' ' 
    AND MAX(SzolgaltatasokDatumig) IS NOT NULL)  T2 
    WHERE  T1.SIRID=T2.sirid
```

but I get:

**"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'T2.MAXDATE FROM SIRADATOK T1'."**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [operation must use an updateable query - access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098031/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-access)

Comment: Saving calculated data, especially aggregate data, is usually unnecessary and even bad practice. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed. Can't run an UPDATE action with a non-updatable query - and that is what an aggregate query is. Your second query is invalid structure, even if the nested query wasn't an aggregate.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using June7 comment, I created the following query that it works:

```
UPDATE 
  SIRADATOK AS T1 
SET 
  T1.MegvaltasIdeje = MID(
    DMAX(
      "SzolgaltatasokDatumig", "Adok", 
      "SzolgaltatasokDatumig<>' ' 
AND SzolgaltatasokDatumig IS NOT NULL AND SIRID=" & T1.SIRID
    ), 
    1, 
    10
  ) 
WHERE 
  DMAX(
    "SzolgaltatasokDatumig", "Adok", 
    "SzolgaltatasokDatumig<>' ' 
AND SzolgaltatasokDatumig IS NOT NULL AND SIRID=" & T1.SIRID
  ) Is Not Null 
  And DMAX(
    "SzolgaltatasokDatumig", "Adok", 
    "SzolgaltatasokDatumig<>' ' 
AND SzolgaltatasokDatumig IS NOT NULL AND SIRID=" & T1.SIRID
  )<> ' '
```

I added an extra MID for the SzolgaltatasokDatumig column, because the column is a DateTime and I need just the Date
I know that is not the best optimized query, but this is just for a one-time use and It works.

thanks again,
June7